# Trac and Subversion not working together

Tags: svn, trac

I installed Trac on my VPS. It loads the pages fine except for reading the svn repository which is working fine on my subversion client

The error i get is

> Warning: Can't synchronize with the
>   repository (Unsupported version
>   control system "svn":
>   "libsvn_fs-1.so.0: cannot open shared
>   object file: No such file or
>   directory" ). Look in the  Trac log
>   for more information.

**Update:**

Regarding [GrayWizardx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932026/trac-and-subversion-not-working-together/1932046#1932046): when I tried to install or fix python svn bindings with:

> `yum install python-subversion`

I get a transaction error:

> file
>   /usr/lib/libsvn_swig_py-1.so.0.0.0
>   from install of
>   subversion-1.6.6-0.1.el5.rf.i386
>   conflicts with file from package
>   subversion-python-1.6.0-1.i386

Comment: Configure your Trac environment to log to a file at DEBUG level, try again, then post the relevant portion of the log.

Answer (score 1):

I found this in the trac-users archive. "[Another unsupported SVN error](http://www.mail-archive.com/trac-users@googlegroups.com/msg04172.html)". it looks similar but it is a different library being reported by the poster. It does have a fix, first reply.

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade subversion-python bindings to the same version as your subversion, i.e. 1.6.6

Answer (score 0):

[Further question as answer merged into OP's question]

Comment: @vk123 Welcome to SO. For future reference, it is common on SO to edit one's question, or add a comment to answers to react, rather than adding an answer oneself.